# button onClick doesn't work second time on listview

Tags: simpleadapter

```
[![the + button doesn't work on second time. The value on qty change only once. Please help me. It has been three weeks.][1]][1]
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_RgLeTUfbjhelB5TndDemtQU3c/view?usp=sharing (Adapter.java)

Comment: This is the pic     https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_RgLeTUfbjhMGZJSEFiXzJ2UVk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please edit your question to add your relevant code